# Visual Basic (VBA) bytes array to a string converting

Tags: vba, decode, encode

I am getting an array of bytes by using of the below code:

```vb
Open filename_ For Binary Access Read As #fileInt
If LOF(fileInt) > 0 Then
    ReDim byteArr(0 To LOF(fileInt) - 1)
    Get #fileInt, , byteArr
    byteArrSize = LOF(fileInt)
    Close #fileInt
    ReadFileAsBinary = byteArr
End If
```

So, I have an array of bytes (byteArr)

How can I convert the array of bytes into astring in VBA knowing that the initial [text] file has [for example] UTF8 char set ?

Is there any elegant solution in VBA like:

Python

```py
str = bytes.decode("utf_8")
```

or

Java

```java
str = String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

?

Comment: This question was already asked. See link above your question.